# Where can I get Paramata Bhanga by Vedanta Desikan?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, vedanta-desika

Where can I get Paramata Bhanga of Vedanta Desikan in English? What are the various schools he discussed there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read an English translation/commentary of an abridged (subset) version here.

https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/Paramata%20Bhangam.pdf

The various schools refuted here are:

1. Lokayata/Charvaka
2. Madhyamika Bauddha
3. Yogachara Bauddha
4. Sautrantika Bauddha
5. Vaibhasika Bauddha
6. Prachchanna Bauddha (Nirvesesha/Sankaran Advaita)
7. Jaina
8. Bhaskara / Yadava School
9. Vyakarana
10. Vaiseshika
11. Gautama Nyaya
12. Nirishvara Purva Mimamsa
13. Nirishvara Saankhya
14. Yoga
15. Paashupata

Apart from refuting the above schools, the school of Pancharatra is defended as well.